# Luxe - "Type not found : UserConfigDef" after updating

Tags: game-engine, haxe, luxe

I've just updated Haxe, Luxe, Hxcpp, etc. on Windows after not using them for a while, and now none of my projects will compile, not even the "empty" sample. I get the following in cmd:

```
C:\GAMEDEV\empty>haxelib run flow run
flow / 1.0.0-alpha.2 (node.js v0.12.7)
flow / target is windows ( arch 32 )
flow / haxe version 3.3.0

flow / build - empty 1.0.0 for windows
flow / build - running haxe ...
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\snow\git\snow/types/Types.hx:72: characters 25-38 : Type
 not found : UserConfigDef

C:\GAMEDEV\empty>
```

Same error when building from Sublime package. Is it possible that I've broken something? Should I attempt to completely reinstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Luxe is not compatible with Haxe 3.3.0-rc1 yet - there is an [open issue](https://github.com/underscorediscovery/luxe/issues/383) about it on GitHub. Try downgrading to [Haxe 3.2.1](https://haxe.org/download/version/3.2.1/).

You may also need to downgrade hxcpp to `3.2.205` if you run into any cpp compilation issues.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I did both and now things run fine. I should have known to check the version support :x